# Blogger HTML Issue with JSC_Parse_Error

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

firstly, I'm no programmer or coder. Just a very basic html user, VERY basic.

I have a small problem which I spent days looking for an answer with no solution.

I want to clean up my html code, so I used Closure Compiler and ran into this;

```
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. primary expression expected at line 1
character 1 in <!DOCTYPE html>
```

How do I fix this? Because closure compiler is not doing anything for me.

This is the first section of my code too;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML b:version='2' class='v2 no-js' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>

<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
<b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/> - <data:blog.title/></title>
</b:if>

<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
<meta content='blogger' name='generator'/>
<link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;favicon.ico&quot;' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
<link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='canonical'/>
<link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default&quot;' expr:title='data:blog.title + &quot; - Atom&quot;' rel='alternate' type='application/atom+xml'/>
<link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default?alt=rss&quot;' expr:title='data:blog.title + &quot; - RSS&quot;' rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml'/>
<link expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/feeds/&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;/posts/default&quot;' expr:title='data:blog.title + &quot; - Atom&quot;' rel='alternate' type='application/atom+xml'/>
<link href='http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g' rel='openid.server'/>
<link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' rel='openid.delegate'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<link expr:href='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' rel='image_src'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != &quot;&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='description'/>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName + &quot; - &quot; + data:blog.title' name='description'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
```

My blog is - http://blog.malaysia-asia.my and I want to fix the html so it oads faster.

I hope someone here can assist me on this problem and thank you in advance.

David

Answer (score 0):

Use a [markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to ensure that the document is valid. It isn't, so fix the issues until the markup passes validation.

As a first step, set the doctype to XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Next, lowercase the document element: `<html ....`